# Sequence in sql operation?

Tags: asp.net

I am passing `datatable` as input parameter to stored procedure. `Datatable` contains `id, Name,Lname,Mobileno,EmpId`.
  `Employee` table contains `[Name],[Lname],[mobno],[Did]` as columns.
  When user is logged in, his `Id` come as `DId`. There are more than 1000 records. Instead of passing that `id` to `datatable`, I have created
  separete parameter to sp. I want to add records to `Employee` table, which are not already exist. If combination of `mobileno` and `Did` already exists, then
  don't insert into `Employee` table, else insert. `Datatable` may contain records, which can be duplicate. So I don't want to include that record. I want select only 
  distinct records and add them to table. I am intrested in `mobile no`. If there are 10 record having same `moble no`, I am fetching record, which comes first.
  Following code is right or wrong. According to my knowledge, first `from clause`, then `inner join`, then `where`, then `select` execute. Record get fetched from `datatable`, 
 then `inner join` happens generate result, from that result not from `datatable` it will check record.  So it will give me proper output.

```
 Create Procedure Proc_InsertEmpDetails
  @tblEmp EmpType READONLY,
  @DId int
  as
begin
INSERT INTO Employee
            ([Name],[Lname],[mobno],[Did])
SELECT [Name],[Lname],[mobno] @DId
FROM   @tblEmp A
Inner join (
             select min(Id) as minID, mobno from @tblEmp group by mobno
           ) MinIDTbl
          on MinIDTbl.minID =  A.ExcelId
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Employee B
                   WHERE  B.[mobno] = A.[mobno]
                   AND B.[Did] =  @DId ) 
end
```

or does I need to change like this

```
INSERT INTO Employee
            ([Name],[Lname],[mobno],[Did])
SELECT C.[Name],C.[Lname],C.[mobno], C.D_Id
from
(SELECT [Name],[Lname],[mobno] @DId as D_Id
FROM   @tblEmp A
Inner join (
                   select min(Id) as minID, mobno from @tblEmp group by mobno
                   ) MinIDTbl
       on MinIDTbl.minID =  A.ExcelId
)C
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   Employee B
                   WHERE  B.[mobno] = C.[mobno]
                          AND B.[Did] =  @DId )
```

Comment: Those two statements are the same.

Comment: One more approach is, you are always selecting first record from the group, so remove duplicates in application itself. It will better performance.